# examples for velocity event

Tags: apache, events, velocity

I use **Apache Click**.

I organize the resource in the group (for example: alert.nofile.found.title alert.nofile.found.text,). So I do not always include the texts programmatic needs (page.addModel ("alertNofileFoundTitle", getMessage ("alert.nofile.found.title"))) I am seeking an opportunity with a velocity intercept the event to match the name of the resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into the ReferenceInsertionEventHandler, i don't know Click, but that is what's generally used for intercepting references in Velocity.